# Как привязать кнопку страницы на Flask к андроид приложению?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, android-studio, flask

Есть web страница localhost Flask на python, на странице 2 кнопки
хочу сделать приложение в android studio с этими двумя кнопками, проще говоря связать их, подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать?

Comment: а что по вашему будут делать эти кнопки?

Comment: Отправлять post запрос, для выполнения другого скрипта на самом сервере

Comment: Ну будет отличатся лишь обращение к серверу нет? с одной стороны по средствам python, с другой java. Т.е. по факту разный синтаксис работы с БД. Кнопки зачем связывать? Если вам нужно лишь заставить отправить запрос?

Comment: Да, именно просто отправить запрос, что бы запустить скрипт питоновский на компе

Comment: Ну получается вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: Вы выяснили просто что мне нужно) Я и сам знаю что мне нужно, а как реализовать, вопрос остался открыт